# Can't upload large file over SFTP

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

For uploading .csv file over SFTP I use [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) (version 2016.0.0).

The file which needs to be sent is rather large (~7GB), and in about an hour after the uploading started it throws the exception **Renci.SshNet.Common.SshOperationTimeoutException: Session operation has timed out**.

Here is my actual uploading code.

```
using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(command.FtpHost, command.UserName, command.Password))
{
    client.Connect();
    client.ChangeDirectory(command.FtpTargetFolder);

    // played a lot with BufferSize property
    // tried to use the default value, tried 4*1024 and 8*1024
    client.BufferSize = 2 * 1024; 

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(command.LocalFilePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        client.UploadFile(fileStream, PrepareFileName(command.LocalFilePath));
    }
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

But this code works fine with smaller (tried with 1-4GB files) files than my desirable one (~7GB). I thought that it could depends on BufferSize, but playing with this property didn't fix the problem.

Here is the issue's stack trace.

```
Renci.SshNet.Common.SshOperationTimeoutException: Session operation has timed out
at Renci.SshNet.Session.WaitOnHandle(WaitHandle waitHandle, TimeSpan timeout)
at Renci.SshNet.Channels.Channel.GetDataLengthThatCanBeSentInMessage(Int32 messageLength)
at Renci.SshNet.Channels.Channel.SendData(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpSession.SendRequest(SftpRequest request)
at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpSession.RequestWrite(Byte[] handle, UInt64 offset, Byte[] data, Int32 length, AutoResetEvent wait, Action'1 writeCompleted)
at Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.InternalUploadFile(Stream input, String path, Flags flags, SftpUploadAsyncResult asyncResult, Action'1 uploadCallback)
```

Also I've noticed that usually uploading throws the error in 1 hour after start and by that time it's uploaded ~80-90% of entire file (because I see not fully uploaded files in my destination SFTP folder).

Comment: is it always one hour? then probably something's timing out your code.

Comment: @MarcB, Not always and not exactly 1 hour - sometimes more, sometimes less. Do you have ideas what possibly can timing it out?

Comment: @AxelKemper, I don't use Duplicati (even have no idea what is it) which is mentioned at the link you've provided, so not sure that it might help.

Comment: [Documentation](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/develop/src/Renci.SshNet/ConnectionInfo.cs) says, that the default timeout is 30s. It might help to set a longer timeout for the `client`. Is there something which could halt your transmission for more than 30s?

Comment: @AxelKemper, it doesn't send file completely at once, it send it chunk by chunk. I'm not sure that this is the right timeout which I need to change. Especially since it works with smaller files (it takes 20 min and more).

Comment: You should consider focusing on making your program handle these failures in a graceful way, by resuming or restarting the transfer, instead of focusing on why the transfer is failing. A 1-hour or more file transfer will always be subject to failing part way through for reasons outside your control.

Comment: @Kenster, yes I understood, but from my view it should be already built in in the library/framework I use. If you don't mind, please provide some examples of what do you mean?